# Gulp not minifying css and JS in specified files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm running `gulp` in an attempt to compile and minify all the `scss` and `js` files found in my theme.

Here is my current folder structure:

```
theme
   assets
      build
         css
            theme.min.css
          js
             theme.min.js
      src
         sass
            globals
               _base.scss
               _client-styles.scss
            _variables.scss
            style.scss
    template-parts
       parts
           hero
              hero.php
              hero.scss
```

And here is what `style.scss` looks like (`assets > src > style.scss`):

```
@import "variables.scss";
@import "globals/**/**.scss";
@import "/../../../template-parts/**/**/*.scss";
```

My aim is, when running gulp, compile everything from the `style.scss` file into `theme.min.css` (`assets > build > css`).

However, when running gulp, the `theme.min.css` file is empty? As in nothing is being compiled and minified. Unsure if I'm missing anything in my gulpfile.js

```js
const assets = 'assets/';
const wpComponents = 'template-parts/';

const gulp          = require('gulp'),
      autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
      concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
      sassGlob      = require('gulp-sass-glob');
const plumber       = require('gulp-plumber'),
      eslint        = require('gulp-eslint');
const scss          = assets + 'src/sass/',
      js            = assets + 'src/js/',
      jsDist        = assets + 'build/js/';
const wpThemeFiles    = wpComponents + '**/**/*.php',
      wpStyleFiles    = scss + '**/*.scss',
      wpJsFiles       = js + '**/*.js';

function css() {
  return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss',scss + 'style.scss'], { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(sassGlob())
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(concat('theme.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(assets + 'build/css/', { sourcemaps: '.' }));
}

function editorCSS() {
  return gulp.src(scss + 'style-editor.scss', { allowEmpty: true })
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(assets + 'build/css/'));
}

function javascript() {
  return gulp.src([
     'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
     'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
     wpJsFiles,
     vcJsFiles
    ])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(concat('theme.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDist));
}

// Lint scripts
function scriptsLint() {
  return gulp
    .src([wpJsFiles, vcJsFiles, "./gulpfile.js"])
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
}

function watch() {
    gulp.watch([wpStyleFiles], css);
    gulp.watch([wpStyleFiles], editorCSS);
    gulp.watch([wpJsFiles], gulp.series( javascript));
    gulp.watch([wpThemeFiles, jsDist + 'scripts.min.js', assets + 'build/css/theme.min.css']);
}

exports.css = css;
exports.editorCSS = editorCSS;
exports.javascript = javascript;
exports.watch = watch;

const build = gulp.series(watch);
gulp.task('default', build);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your style.scss imports correctly referencing the directories of the other scss files?

It looks like:

`@import "globals/**/**.scss";`

is searching an extra directory deeper than the file is actually located

Comment: Ah, many thanks, it seems to be compiling it into `theme.min.css` now. Although, the css isn't minified, it's just compiled css with blank lines in between. Am I missing something?